# What is the most efficiant way to check if an exception is thrown for all statements in junit?

Tags: java, exception, junit

I've got a function which throws a `ParseException` when given an invalid input, and I would like to write a unit test for it.  This test is intended to make sure that an exception is thrown on all invalid inputs.  (For this question, just assume that an input is defined as valid if it starts with a `[`, ends with a `]`, and has no `[`'s or `]`'s anywhere else in it.)

I currently have this test:

```
@Test
public void invalidListFromatShouldFail() {        
    final String[] tests = {
            "[[]",
            "[]]",
            "[] hi",
            "hi",
            "[h]i",
            "[hi []",
            "[[]]"
    };

    for(String toTest : tests) {
        try {
            ListUtil.parseList(toTest, TestEnum.class);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            assertThat(e.getMessage(), startsWith(
                    "§cList format is invalid: It must start with " +
                    "'[' and end with ']', and not have any '['" + 
                    " or ']' anywhere else in it."));
            continue;
        }
        fail("Exception was not thrown for " + toTest + "!");
    }
}
```

And it works, but it doesn't seem like the proper way.  I tried using [`ExpectedException`](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html), but the code still exits immediately.  (What I tried was this:

```
@Test
public void invalidListFromatShouldFail() throws ParseException {
    expected.expect(ParseException.class);
    expected.expectMessage(startsWith(
                    "§cList format is invalid: It must start with " +
                    "'[' and end with ']', and not have any '['" + 
                    " or ']' anywhere else in it."));

    ListUtil.parseList("[[]", TestEnum.class);
    ListUtil.parseList("[]]", TestEnum.class);
    //ECT...
}
```

but that only tests the first value; if I were to put a `fail()` at the very end it still would succeed because the exception occurred).

My question is: Is there a more elegant way to write this test, using [`ExpectedException`](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you seem to need two things here. One is writing a test that checks that an exception was thrown and the other is running the same test for multiple inputs.

First, start by parametrizing your test. In this approach your test method is written so that it only runs for a single input, and additional code (usually annotations) make this method run for multiple inputs. This makes your code simpler because you don't have to write the loop or put data in some array or list. You can use JUnit's built-in `Parameterized` test runner for this ([docs and example](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html)) but I personally find its syntax cumbersome. My recommendation would be for you to use [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams) which has very concise and sweet syntax.

For checking that an exception was thrown in a method that tests a single input, you can use the `expected` parameter in `@Test` annotation. An alternative would be using [catch-exception library](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) which is nicer if you have longer tests. Here, I think the built-in is good enough.

So, using JUnitParams and the `expected` annotation parameter, your test could look like this:

```
@Test(expected = ParseException.class)
@Parameters(
    "[[]",
    "[]]",
    "[] hi",
    "hi",
    "[h]i",
    "[hi []",
    "[[]]"
)
public void invalidListFromatShouldFail(String input) {        
    ListUtil.parseList(toTest, TestEnum.class);
}
```

This is quite short and readable as well.

*EDIT:* [Here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) is a better example of using `Parameterized`, which also mentions `@Parameter` annotation which allows you to inject values directly into a field without the need to create a constructor in your test class. Still, having used both, I really recommend JUnit Params over `Parameterized` as the difference in ease of use and test readability is huge.

Comment: Just to confirm, with the built-in Parameterized runner, would that end up running the same code multiple times?  Only one of the functions needs to be run more than once with these parameters.  (I probably should just try this myself).

Comment: Usage would be quite similar, that is: you write a method which checks a single input, and `Parameterized` runner takes care of running this method for the different inputs. You don't have to write any loop yourself. Compared to JUnitParams, there will be more code, but the idea is mostly the same. However, JUnitParams will be much more convenient to use than `Parameterized` if you want to have several methods in your class, some parametrized and some not, or parameterized methods taking different arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Use JUnit parameterized tests : https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests

As an alternative you can use JUnitParams : https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams

Cheers,

Comment: Also split the valid input from the invalid input. Then use the @Test(expected = YourException.class) on the parameterized test you expect to fail

Comment: Indeed keep your tests as simple as possible. Use two separate @Test methods : one that tests the behaviour of your code when valid input is provided, and a second one that tests the behaviour when invalid input is provided. The first one should expect None.class, the second should expect ParseException.class.

Answer (score -1):

You need to annotate your test with:

```
@Test(expected = YourException.class)
```

here's a good tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-2-expected-exception-test/

also have a look at parametrized tests: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: This isn't what I want.  I'm trying to have it test in multiple cases.  This would do the exact same thing as using ExpectedException, and only check the first value.

Comment: If only you people were so quick with posting answers as you are with downvoting...

Comment: @Pokechu22 I understand, see second link - that's what you need

Comment: Write a complete useable answer that adresses the question before posting it as an answer, and you will not get as many downvotes. You have edited this answer several times, and it is still not a useful answer.

Comment: but I guess it's down to OP to look at parametrized tests and see for himself

Comment: @Lucas That second bit actually looks useful, but the main part of this answer is not useful.  If you could post a new answer with that bit it would be nice, but as it stands it isn't a useful answer to the question.